# Secure WebSocket (WSS) in Java server and client in javascript

Tags: websocket

**WebSocket** connection to `wss://localhost:8025/websockets/server` failed: **WebSocket** opening handshake timed out

Please help what I'm doing wrong !

---

Server side code:

To start server

```
Server server = new Server("localhost", 8025, "/websockets", WebSocketServerEndpoint.class);
server.start();

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/server")
public class WebSocketServerEndpoint {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws Exception 
    {
        Logger.write("communication_clientservice", "WebSocket >> Connected ... " + session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException 
    {
        Logger.write("communication_clientservice_websocket", "UI to Websocket >> command received at Websocket >> " + message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) throws IOException 
    {
        Logger.write("communication_clientservice_websocket", "WebSocket >>"+ String.format("Session %s closed because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));   
        session.close();
    }
}
```

---

Client side
client to connect server

```
 var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8025/websockets/server");             
               ws.maxTimeout = 5 * 1000;
               ws.onopen = function()
               {
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("{\"from\":\"shabeer\"}");
                  //alert("Message is sent...");
                  var elem = document.getElementById("receivedmsg");
                  elem.innerHTML = "panic request send";
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
               { 
                  var received_msg = evt;
                  //alert("Message is received..." + received_msg);
                  var elem = document.getElementById("receivedmsg");
                  elem.innerHTML = "Response received : " + received_msg;
               };

               ws.onclose = function()
               { 
                  // websocket is closed.
                  ///alert("Connection is closed..."); 
                  setTimeout(function(){WebSocketTest()}, 5000);
               };
```

---

Comment: Do you have any authorization issue? I.e. are you able to access `https://...your domain.../..your context root.../server/` ?

Comment: Are you implementing the SSL certificate pinning ?

Comment: Are you implementing SSL in any way at the server end? No evidence of it here.

Answer (score -1):

Web Socket server starts with ws(unsecured like HTTP) by default. If you need SSL (WSS), it has to be explicitly set in your server object.

If you use the below URL in your client, it should work.

```
wss://localhost:8025/ to ws://localhost:8025/
```

Comment: As he clearly wants SSL it would have been more to the point to show how to do that.